# jupyter lab 3 cannot display ipyaggrid

Tags: widget, jupyter-lab

when trying to display an ipyaggrid object, i get:
"Error displaying widget: model not found".

the same notebook works fine in jupyter notebook.

Here is
"conda list jupyter"

```
# packages in environment at C:\Users\cocoj\.conda\envs\py39:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
jupyter                   1.0.0            py39haa95532_7
jupyter-packaging         0.7.12             pyhd3eb1b0_0
jupyter_client            6.1.12             pyhd3eb1b0_0
jupyter_console           6.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jupyter_core              4.7.1            py39haa95532_0
jupyter_server            1.4.1            py39haa95532_0
jupyterlab                3.0.14             pyhd3eb1b0_1
jupyterlab_pygments       0.1.2                      py_0
jupyterlab_server         2.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jupyterlab_widgets        1.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
```

and here is the "jupyter labextension list"

```
JupyterLab v3.0.14
C:\Users\cocoj\.conda\envs\py39\share\jupyter\labextensions
        jupyterlab-plotly v5.2.2 enabled ok
        @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager v3.0.0 enabled ok (python, jupyterlab_widgets)
        @voila-dashboards/jupyterlab-preview v2.0.2 enabled ok (python, voila)

Other labextensions (built into JupyterLab)
   app dir: C:\Users\cocoj\.conda\envs\py39\share\jupyter\lab
        ipyaggrid v0.2.1 enabled ok
```

fwiw, the ipywidgets, the plotly figureWidgets are all displayed fine in Jupyter Lab.

[image: Further debug]

in particular,

> 523.fa256ee012d38a89b65a.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Module ipyaggrid, semver range ~0.2.1 is not registered as a widget module

Comment: https://gitlab.com/DGothrek/ipyaggrid/-/issues/37
"note. i think conflicting jupyter lab extension dependencies was causing issues in the first place. For the above when i added the ipysheet extension ipyaggrid stopped rendering. running the jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager  command again fixed it with both extensions functioning correctly with jupyter lab 3. I was coming into similar issues on the Windows side."
however i tried the above and still does not work

Comment: I have the same problem with latest JupyterLab 3.2.5